# git rebase, commits repeating

Tags: git, rebase

I'm working on another branch of my repo and need to bring in changes from the master branch. I'm in the habit of doing `git rebase master`, and all works fine. However, in a couple of recent projects, I'm seeing commits repeating in the logs, and rebasing tends to complain (loudly):

```
$ git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate ...
*   4988d49 - (2 hours ago) Merge branch 'branchname' of ... 3
|\
| * e979be1 - (2 days ago) change verbiage 10
| *   93a1c80 - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'branchname' of ... 2
| |\
| | *   4e4e790 - (2 weeks ago) Merge branch 'branchname' of ... 1
| | |\
| | | * 87cc232 - (8 weeks ago) change verbiage 3
| | | * 3d5cf09 - (8 weeks ago) change verbiage 2
| | | * aea4cbd - (9 weeks ago) change verbiage 1
| | * | a7043ef - (2 weeks ago) change verbiage 6
| | * | fa3413b - (2 weeks ago) change verbiage 5
| | * | be038a7 - (2 weeks ago) change verbiage 4
| | * | 37cb1e6 - (8 weeks ago) change verbiage 3
| | * | 1ab71c6 - (8 weeks ago) change verbiage 2
| | * | c4560f4 - (9 weeks ago) change verbiage 1
| * | | d3211fd - (2 weeks ago) change verbiage 6
| * | | 72a2a4a - (2 weeks ago) change verbiage 5
| * | | ae1c123 - (2 weeks ago) change verbiage 4
| * | | 8328c08 - (8 weeks ago) change verbiage 3
| * | | e52588f - (8 weeks ago) change verbiage 2
| * | | 114cbec - (9 weeks ago) change verbiage 1
* | | | 38bd6ce - (2 hours ago) change verbiage 9
* | | | 5aaf360 - (2 hours ago) change verbiage 8
* | | | 2745790 - (2 days ago) change verbiage 7
* | | | 7bb613f - (2 weeks ago) change verbiage 6
* | | | 726a312 - (2 weeks ago) change verbiage 5
* | | | 771dd7f - (2 weeks ago) change verbiage 4
* | | | b451926 - (8 weeks ago) change verbiage 3
* | | | 484d5dc - (8 weeks ago) change verbiage 2
* | | | 630df34 - (9 weeks ago) change verbiage 1
```

(I've changed the commit messages for simplicity. There really is only one branch being displayed here, despite four "pipe lines".) I've done a few rebases on this project, and I think they can be traced rather simply based on the number of repeats of (say) change verbiage 1.

I thought I was doing a "best practices" thing with project workflow by rebasing to merge. I thought at least one of the previous rebases was done with `-no-ff`, but I cannot see a difference in the behavior.

When the commits are replayed, they conflict (obviously, placing one commit on top of itself is problematic), so I'm forced to do an interactive rebase, removing all duplicate commits.

Lacking access to the repo itself, is this a problem with my workflow? Is it indicative of other problems in the branch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Why?

It looks like you modified old commits with rebase that another branch was already pointing too. So what happened is:

You had a dag that looks like this:

```
* abc123 (master) Most recent commit
|
| * f00ba12 (foo, HEAD) Some feature you're working on
| |
|/
* 192837 Fix the things
|
* 348cc87 Remove Peter's garbage code
|
* 000a0a WOOOORRRDDDDDSSSS
```

So you're currently on `foo` doing some things but you realize you still have some of Peter's garbage code left over and want to remove it. Being the good programmer you are, you want those changes to be in commit `348cc87` along with the rest of that change. So you do a rebase to get back to that point and amend the changes in.

This seems fine right? Thing is, you've changed `348cc87` so it's not `348cc87` anymore. Now its `111222`, because remember the commit hash is calculated from the project's tree, among other things. One of those other things is parent commit hash (`000a0a`). So since `348cc87` is now `111222`, '192837' is recalculated to `999999` and `f00ba12` changes to `ba12f00`. So now your log from HEAD looks like

```
* ba12f00 (foo, HEAD) Some feature you're working on
|
|
* 999999 Fix the things
|
* 111222 Remove Peter's garbage code
|
* 000a0a WOOOORRRDDDDDSSSS
```

This becomes an issue because `abc123` *is still pointing at `192837`*, which works because the commit object `192837` still exists in git. This is because from git's perspective `192837` and `abc123` are distinctly different commits that just happen to have the same log message.

So now your git dag looks like:

```
* abc123 (master) Most recent commit
|
| * f00ba12 (foo, HEAD) Some feature you're working on
| |
| * 999999 Fix the things
* | 192837 Fix the things
| | 
| * 111222 Remove Peter's garbage code
* | 348cc87 Remove Peter's garbage code
|/
* 000a0a WOOOORRRDDDDDSSSS
```

Now when you finish working on your `foo` branch and are ready to merge you get

```
* 5f93da (master) Merge 'foo' into 'master'
|\
* | abc123 Most recent commit
| |
| * f00ba12 (foo, HEAD) Some feature you're working on
| |
| * 999999 Fix the things
* | 192837 Fix the things
| | 
| * 111222 Remove Peter's garbage code
* | 348cc87 Remove Peter's garbage code
|/
* 000a0a WOOOORRRDDDDDSSSS
```

Do this a lot and you end up in the situation you are currently in.

But Kyle, how do I fix this?? Hold your horses r2evans, I'm getting there.

## How to Fix

There are a few ways you could fix this, all of the ones I am aware of are mildly complicated given certain circumstances.

- You could squash lots of stuff together so that there are fewer commits, but you lose some of your history, which I don't love.
- You can do some more rebasing magic to change your 'abc123' commit to have the newer `999999` commit as it's parent. You can use the --onto argument for this. This can be challenging depending on the number of commits in this situation.
- You can leave it as it is. So long as the tip of master is in the correct state, this isn't *horrible* but makes looking back on your history pretty difficult.

## Is This a Problem?

Yes. This looks like a problem with your workflow. Editing history tends to be a less than great idea for this very reason and you should typically avoid it.

For me, `master` tracks what is public. It is the code that both myself and my teammates base our changes off of. I never modify commits that are in master. Firstly because our internal git repo won't allow me to push changes like that (even with --force) and secondly because that would mess with my teammates' code (and put them into your position).

I create feature branches off of `master` for specific features so I will have branches `foo`, `bar`, `fizz`, and `buzz` all as separate branches off of master, not off each other. This allows me to work on each independently. I don't typically branch off of a feature branch, but when I do, I generally don't do any editing of commit histories. That's because I'll generally clean up the branch before merging anyway, so I don't need to.

Comment: Very well fashioned answer, thanks Kyle. The other problem (I forgot to mention) is that I do have the branch on the repo server, so `git push origin` almost always requires an obligatory commit before being able to push. Perhaps my biggest "issue" with my presented dag is that it shows four branches when there is only one; I would prefer to keep a "clean" dag without obviously-repeating commit messages. Knowing that this is "normal behavior" helps.

Comment: If entire history is already out for the world to see and people are consuming it, just leave it. This isn't great or anything, but you shouldn't be messing with public repos as that hurts other developers. So once you push to origin, you should make new commits rather than rebase into old commits.